# Laravel 5.2 Redirect::back()->with e Redirect::back()->withErrors não funciona

Tags: laravel, route, laravel-5.2

Já desenvolvi diversas aplicações com Laravel. O problema surgiu quando derrepente na versão 5.2 o comando Redirect::back()->with e Redirect::back()->withErrors parou de funcionar. Pesquisei na internet e só achei solução do tipo para adicionar o middleware web nos routes. Coisa que eu faço. Veja um exemplo do meu route que não funciona:

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
        Route::get("/teste", function(){
            return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::back()->with('success', ['Database Error!']);
        });

        Route::get("/teste2", function(){
            if(Session::has("success")) echo Session::get('success');
        });
    });
```

Não está funcionando de jeito algum, antes o meu blade erá do seguinte modo e também não funcionava.

```
            <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns ErroPanel">
                @if ($errors->any())
                    <div class="alert callout closable">
                        <ul class="alert alert-warning">
                            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endif
                @if (Session::has("success"))
                    <div class="success callout closable">
                        <ul class="alert alert-success">
                            @foreach(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::get("success") as $success)
                                <li>{{ $success }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
```

Kernel.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}
```

**Solução**

Fiz a remoção da linha `Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {` do meu route e começou a funcionar, o que eu não entendo que meu arquivo veio com esta linha como padrão, mas já avia sido adicionada como padrão tambem no RouteServiceProvider dando conflito. Por fim, agora está funcionando, devo abrir uma issue no git do laravel informando o erro?

Comment: O with não tem de levar como parametro um array?

Comment: Não, ele é daquele mesmo modo. with('nome', 'valor').

Comment: Como está o seu Http\Kernel @PedroSoares ?

Comment: Acabei de adiciona-lo.

Comment: Com certeza, essa pergunta, mesmo não sendo duplicada, já tem uma resposta.

Comment: Não sei @WallaceMaxters, ele está aplicando o middleware diretamente na rota... era pra funcionar independente do RouteProvider....

Comment: @gmsantos sim, mas se observar, dependendo da versão, como eu disse na resposta, o middleware será declarado duas vezes, causando problemas na sessão. Pelo menos foi o que ocorreu comigo, mas sim, pode ser outro caso.